# How to handle periodically changing database data in your Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, database-schema

> EDIT: I have totally rewritten this question for clarity. I got no comments and no answers earlier.

I am maintaining a 2.x Rails app with plenty of statistical data. Some data is real and some is estimated for the future years. Every year I need to update estimated data with real data and calculate new estimates.

I have been using BIG yml-files and migrations for loading the data into the app every year. My migrations are full of estimation calculations and data corrections.

---

**Problem**

My migrations are full of none-schema related material and I can't even dream of doing db:migrate:reset without waiting few hours (if it even works). I'd love to see my migrations nice and clean - only with schema related modifications. But how I am suppose to update the data every year if not using migrations?

---

**Help needed**

*I'd like to hear your comments and answers. I'm not looking for a silver bullet - more like best practises and ideas how people are handling similar situation.*

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I should try to edit this question. It's quite messy. Even I wouldn't like to answer this. Well I got Tumbleweed badge for this :)

Comment: I have totally rewritten this question for clarity. Any comments and answers are highly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for the answers. @Adrian suggested using rake task, @lucapette mentioned the seeds.rb approach. Seeds is more for a initial db input and with rake tasks I'm still waiting a bit more info from Adrian. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Plenty of good answers here! @abdollar, your answer suites best for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a large operation (data load using yml files) once a year but smaller operations once a month.

From my experience with statistical data you will probably end up doing more and more of these operations to clean and add more data.

I would use a job processing framework like [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) and [resque scheduler](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler).

You can schedule the jobs to run once a month, year, day or constantly running. A job is something like loading yml files (or sets of yml files) or cleaning up data. You can control parameters to send to your job so you can use one class but alternate how it updates or cleans your data based on the way you enqueue or schedule the job.

Comment: thanks! I really liked the idea of resque. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I have to say that this is a very interesting question. As far as i know, it isn't a good idea loading data from migrations. Generally speaking you should use db/seeds.rb for data loading in your db and I think it could be a good idea to write a little class helper to put in your lib dir and then call it from db/seeds.rb. I image you could organize you files in the following way:

```
lib/data_loader.rb
lib/years/2009.rb
lib/years/2010.rb
```

Obviously, you should clear your migrations and write code for lib/data_loader.rb in the way you should prefer but I was only trying to offer a general idea of how I'd organize my code if I have to face a problem like that.

I'm not sure I've replied to your question in a way that helps but I hope it does.

Comment: thanks for the post! I have understood that seeds are used mainly for inputting initial data to the db. I quite did not understand how seeds.rb can be used for updating data yearly. With this approach how I should call rake db:seed once I need to update the db content?

Comment: You're welcome, you can write your "data_loader" in the way it can handle the "year thing". I was thinking something like "data_loader.load_current_year" but reading the other response I think you should go with that either. Using a task could even be a finer solution, you should write a task that takes the year to load as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks! [According to DHH](http://twitter.com/dhh/statuses/27425849821110272) seeds should be used first time you setup the database. The problem is really to keep the seeds.rb up-to-date if I want to have the possibility to start from scratch. The initial data kind of keeps changing all the time :)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would go with creating custom rake task. You will have access to all you models and activerecord connections and once a year you will end up doing:

```
rake calculate
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Few questions. About the data, how would you load the new data in with rake task? Using yml-files? I forgot to meantion that besides the BIG operation every year I do have smaller tweaks for the data (corrections mainly) maybe once every month. With rake tasks, I would end up having tens of rake tasks. And I would need to keep track of the execution order as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a situation where I need to load data from CSV files that change infrequently and update data from the Internet daily. I'll include a somewhat complete example on how to do the former.

---

First I have a rake file in `lib/tasks/update.rake`:

```
require 'update/from_csv_files.rb'

namespace :update do

  task :csvfiles => :environment do
    Dir.glob('db/static_data/*.csv') do |file|
      Update::FromCsvFiles.load(file)
    end
  end

end
```

The `=> :environment` means we will have access to the database via the usual models.

Then I have code in the `lib/update/from_csv_files.rb` file to do the actual work:

```
require 'csv'

module Update
  module FromCsvFiles

    def FromCsvFiles.load(file)
      csv = CSV.open(file, 'r')
      csv.each do |row|
        id = row[0]

        s = Statistic.find_by_id(id)
        if (s.nil?)
          s = Statistic.new
          s.id= id
        end

        s.survey_area = row[1]
        s.nr_of_space_men = row[2]
        s.save
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Then I can just run `rake update:csvfiles` whenever my CSV files changes to load the new data. I also have another task that is set up in a similar way to update my daily data.

---

In your case you should be able to write some code to load your YML files or make your calculations directly. To handle your smaller corrections you could make a generic method for loading YML files and call it with specific files from the rake task. That way you only need to include the YML file and update the rake file with a new task. To handle execution order you can make a rake task that calls the other rake tasks in the appropriate order. I'm just throwing around some ideas now, you know better than me.

Comment: Thanks @Gieron for the answer. This looks handy way of dealing with CSV input. Nice!